# XML parsing with shell script

Tags: shell, unix, scripting

I am having issues while I am trying to get some data from the text filed of the xml tag.

This filed is repeated many times in the xml.

```
<abc>
<def>
<gh tag="ext" text="1. look
2. for 
3. this 
4. if
5. what">
</gh>
</def>
</abc>
```

What I have done is to grep the pattern and loop till the `">` reached. But I am also getting some other data also. Can someone please help me with that or show me the direction. I tried perl but XML library where missing.

Comment: Perl modules can be installed in your home directory. You don't have to install them in a "system" location.

Answer (score 3):

Please use [the correct tool](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/).

```
$ xmlstarlet sel -t -m abc/def/gh -v @text input.xml
1. look 2. for 3. this 4. if 5. what
```

Comment: i am not having this tool on my server. and dnont have permission to install anything

Comment: Then you're screwed. Have fun.

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to adapt the AWK script found [here](http://awk.info/?XML).

Answer (score 1):

**sgrep** - Structured Grep  - used in searching and indexing XML , HTML.

http://www.cs.helsinki.fi/u/jjaakkol/sgrepexamples.html

Answer (score 0):

A quick and dirty solution -

```
awk '/text="/,/">/{print}' xmlfile | sed -e 's/^\(<gh.*="\)//' -e 's/">$//'
```